# How to make a secondary WIFI network with 1 router

Tags: wireless-networking

I have realised with guests at my house that whilst I'm more than happy for them to use my WiFi I do find that I'm not able to keep a consistent speed whilst downloading and streaming.

Is it possible to make a second network on the same router? I have a NetGear CG3100.

Lastly I was wondering if it would be possible to limit the speed of the guest WiFi network.
Is it also possible to make sure that the guest network doesn't take priority and therefore will not effect the speed of the my own non guest network on the same router?

If this is not possible on one router, please explain how I might go about it with 2 routers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [User Manual](https://www.comhem.se/asset/rqq4gefrk8ol/10sdhzs6R0Yi20OcqomCkk/3658d7d4d5a28043aec8d832dc419931/manual-netgear-cg3100-data.pdf) for your router, I do not believe your router supports creating multiple SSID's.

The simplest(and likely cheapest) way to solve your problem is to buy an access point with configurable SSID and connect it with an inferior cable (two twisted pairs can only provide 10/100 Mbit speeds). Depending on the internet speed provided by your ISP, a 10Mbit cable might be limiting enough for you to still use the remaining bandwidth un-throttled at relatively high speeds. *I am not sure this would work, I have never tried it.*

In the case of two routers; Based of [this](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-WiFi-Routers/How-to-change-the-SSID-of-an-Access-Point/m-p/1255791/highlight/true#M53385) Netgear community post I would *assume* that you can configure the second router by simply accessing its control panel via its local IP, that you would be able to see in the main routers control panel. If the router does not support throttling then you can use the "trick" from before

Answer (score 0):

If your router supports creating a 2nd network, you should be able to create one from the router's interface. There you should find options to limit bandwith for the 2nd network. Again, this also depends on whether your router supports these functions.

If you can't limit bandwith in your router's interface, creating a second network will do nothing to make your own speed more consistent.

If you want to try it with a second router, search for "router behind router" with your router's model name. This should point you to the right path. Generally, you'll need to make the first router the gateway of the second router.